# Rails 3 & jQuery - autocomplete & send form after click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, jquery-autocomplete

I think about the solution of situation, when after typing a few letters you will get a words from database and after click on a loaded word will be send the form?

In the basic shape about **autocomplete**, so after click on a loaded word will this word set to input.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear - but I'm guessing that after autocomplete you want to automatically submit the form.  You can do this by calling submit in the select callback

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what implementation of autocomplete you are using but if you are using the jQuery-UI autocomplete widget there is a callback you can put right in the autocomplete configuration hash:

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
  select: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

If you aren't using this widget then my answer isn't as terribly useful of course and I apologize. There isn't a lot of detail in your question.

On a side note, if you're using a home grown autocomplete implementation I'd strongly suggest you investigate the [jQuery-UI option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)